# Slim Application Error due not a class or valid container entry

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to use the slim framework to build a website, however I get the following error: "Cannot call index on Store\HomeController because it is not a class nor a valid container entry." I have thoroughly checked for spelling and punctuation errors and found none.  The error go's to line 98 of a "callableResover.php file of the following code:

```
throw new NotCallableException(sprintf(
    'Cannot call %s on %s because it is not a class nor a valid container entry',
    $callable[1],
    $callable[0]
));
```

This is the HomeController.php file the I created as the following:
namespace Store\Controllers;

```
class HomeController{
  public function index(){
    echo('Index');

  }//end function index

}//end class
```

And this the route.php file of the code following:

```
$app->get('/', ['Store\HomeController', 'index'])->setName('home');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HomeController file is loaded before using it in your `route.php` file, try to:

#### 1. Add a `\` to your controller's namespace in the route definition

```
\Store\HomeController
```

#### 2. Change your route to this one instead

```
$app->get('/', \Store\HomeController::class . ':index');
```

Check the Slim documentation to learn more about [container resolution](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#container-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem..
The class is probably registred in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

so you have to regenerate it with command
`composer dump-autoload`

and it should work...